# Adding user(/plugin/thirdparty) data to IDB files

Tags: ida, idapython

I think I've seen it somewhere a few years back, but couldn't find a mention anywhere.

I'm developing an IDAPython plugin and I'd like to embed IDB-specific information inside IDBs. Obviously, I could write that data into another file but embedding it into IDB files will really suit my needs.

The data itself is quite simple and small, I could do with few tens (hundred max) of bytes. I can go one binary blob or free-text/json that I manually manage.

I thought about adding a section of my own, but that's a bit too hacky and IDA instances without my plugin will show it to the user.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `netnode`. check out https://github.com/williballenthin/ida-netnode .

Comment: Thanks, i was actually looking for netnode in general, not specifically for a third party tool around it, though it did help me find the API.